# Can an application for a website publish to it's wall like fan pages do?

Tags: facebook-wall, facebook-page, feed

This is what an application (a facebook app) can do as I've seen (among other things... like a facebook tab):

User A clicks the like button inside the website www.example.com.
The user's friends see, in their news feed, that user A "likes a link", they see the name of the site that is a link, and if they click on it, they go to the URL of the site (www.example.com).
I know that the website with the application (facebook app) (www.example.com) can also create a button "allow posting to my wall", and when user A (or any user) hits it, gets a dialog from Facebook asking for permissions for that application to publish to the wall. But that's not what I want...

Now, a fan page:

User A enters in the fan page inside facebook (www.facebook.com/example) and hits the "like" button.
User A's friends get in their news feed that "User A likes Example", and when they click that link they go to the fan page in facebook (www.facebook.com/example).
Now, when the fan page updates it's status in it's wall (the fan page's wall), user A can see that in his news feed.

Now, this is what I want:

User A hits the "like" button inside the web (www.example.com).
User A's friends see, in their news feed, that "User A likes Example", and when they click it they go to www.example.com (not www.facebook.com/example).
The application (facebook app) that they liked (www.example.com) can publish a status update in it's own wall, so the users that liked it can see updates (written by the application/website, not by another user) in their news feeds.

Can it be done and how?

All I have seen everywhere is about posting on behalf of an user, not by the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do this. only Fan Pages and Facebook application profile can update your news wall.

If you want, create an Facebook application and put your website in the configuration and when they click "Goto App" they will be redirected to Example.com.

Comment: Allan, thank you, I will let this open to see if anyone else has a solution... 

I still think that the Facebook API is very big and may have this functionality somewhere, hidden in the not-so-well organized documentation.

Comment: I never seen any websites updating your Wall Posts , it's better to have a Facebook APP or Facebook Fanpage for that task.

Comment: Allan, that's what I'm referring to when I say "applicaton", a "facebook app", the one that get's an "app secret", an app_id (that code that goes in a "meta" element inside the website), etc. Can a facebook app do that?

I'll update the question.

Comment: Are you familiar with Social Reader? Check it out! I think Yahoo and Washington Post is using that app but i don't know in some indiviuals.